# Reload XML Layout in Xamarin.Android on Orientation Change?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create two different layouts for portrait and landscape mode in Xamarin for my Android app.

I have created a layout folder for portrait mode, and layout-land for landscape. When I open the specific page, the correct layout is loaded based on the device's orientation. However, when I change the orientation while the page is already open, the layout does not change and only rotates. I have tried overriding `OnConfigurationChanged` in the `mainActivity`, but I am unsure how to call and load the layout for only the desired page.

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig) 
{
    base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait) 
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myLayout);
    } 
    else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape) 
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myLayout);
    }
}
```

This code loads the correct layout on orientation change, but it is called anytime the orientation is changed and occurs outside of the desired page that this layout is associated with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Xamarin.Forms**, you have events like `LayoutChanged` and `SizeChanged`, that fires whenever the **Layout** of a **Page** changes (this includes when the page is created, and when orientation changes), so might be a good place to look at.

In the article suggested below by @jgoldberger-MSFT, the team at Xamarin recommend the use of `SizeChanged` (read the article for further details!)

> Xamarin.Forms does not offer any native events for notifying your app of orientation changes in shared code. However, the SizeChanged event of the Page fires when either the width or height of the Page changes.

Inside a **ContentPage** in **Xamarin.Forms** you can simply set (super basic example):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SizeChanged += (s,a) =>
    {
        if (this.Width > this.Height ) // or any flag that you use to check the current orientation!
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        else
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    };
}
```

---

**Update:**

In **Page Renderer** in **Android** you might still be able to use the similar `LayoutChange` **Handler**:

```
class Class1 : PageRenderer
{

    public Class1(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        LayoutChange += (s, a) =>
        {

        };
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful...

Comment: Thank you. Would I be able to use this inside of an android page as well? Currently I am using a renderer in my Android project to create my page.

Comment: Ouh! I am not sure, i never tried that. It might be helpful if you add that detail (i mean, that you want a solution for the Renderer in Android) in your question Post. Because of your tag (Xamarin.Forms) I assumed you would be happy with a Xamarin.Forms solution! :P

Comment: @zack, just checked. PageRenderer in Android also has a LayoutChange Event. You could give it a try! (Updated answer)

Comment: this may be a worthwhile read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows

Comment: @zack, if this solved your problem/question, please accept as the answer. If not, please share more details on your further problems, of if you already found the right answer yourself please share it here so that other can also profit!